# Invalid declaration of the logger in springboot

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin

> I use spring boot with kotlin I added lombook Dependency in my
> gradle.kt but when I use log.info() function I am getting error .I
> also define logger details in a separate file which name
> logback-spring.xml
> I don't know why I am getting error in log declaration .where I used
> log.Info() in my order controller at the log I get error
> it show me an instruction "**Unresolved reference: log**" or create a
> local variable log
> Here is the error

```
Unresolved reference: log
```

> OrderController.kt

```
package com.main.orderservice.controller

import com.main.orderservice.client.InventoryClient
import com.main.orderservice.entity.Order
import com.main.orderservice.model.OrderDto
import com.main.orderservice.repository.OrderRepository
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.cloud.circuitbreaker.resilience4j.Resilience4JCircuitBreaker
import org.springframework.cloud.circuitbreaker.resilience4j.Resilience4JCircuitBreakerFactory
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.function.StreamBridge
import org.springframework.messaging.support.MessageBuilder
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController
import java.util.*
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService
import java.util.function.Supplier


@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/order")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
class OrderController {
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var orderRepository: OrderRepository
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var inventoryClient: InventoryClient
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var circuitBreakerFactory: Resilience4JCircuitBreakerFactory
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var streamBridge: StreamBridge
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var traceableExecutorService: ExecutorService

    @PostMapping
    fun placeOrder(@RequestBody orderDto: OrderDto): String {
        circuitBreakerFactory.configureExecutorService(traceableExecutorService)
        val circuitBreaker: Resilience4JCircuitBreaker = circuitBreakerFactory.create("inventory")
        val booleanSupplier =
            Supplier<Boolean> {
                orderDto.OrderLineItemList?.stream()
                    ?.allMatch { lineItem ->
                        log.info("Making Call to Inventory Service for SkuCode {}", lineItem.skuCode)
                        inventoryClient.checkStock(lineItem.skuCode)
                    }
            }
        val productsInStock = circuitBreaker.run(booleanSupplier
        ) { throwable: Throwable? -> handleErrorCase() }
        return if (productsInStock) {
            val order = Order()
            order.orderList = orderDto.OrderLineItemList
            order.orderNumber=UUID.randomUUID().toString()
            orderRepository.save(order)
            log.info("Sending Order Details with Order Id {} to Notification Service", order.id)
            streamBridge.send("notificationEventSupplier-out-0", MessageBuilder.withPayload(order.id).build())
            "Order Place Successfully"
        } else {
            "Order Failed - One of the Product in your Order is out of stock"
        }
    }

    private fun handleErrorCase(): Boolean {
        return false
    }



}
```

> logback-spring.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml"/>
    <appender name="logstash" class="net.logstash.logback.appender.LogstashTcpSocketAppender">
        <destination>localhost:5000</destination>
        <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LoggingEventCompositeJsonEncoder">
            <providers>
                <mdc />
                <context />
                <logLevel />
                <loggerName />
                <pattern>
                    <pattern>
                        {
                        "appName": "order-service"
                        }
                    </pattern>
                </pattern>
                <threadName />
                <message />
                <logstashMarkers />
                <stackTrace />
            </providers>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="logstash" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Comment: -javaagent for lombok should be added in .ini file.

Answer (score 0):

> First of all to declare Logger of slf4j then add the class, in which
> you want to use logger by the help of LoggerFactory. Like this
> OrderController.kt

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/order")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
class OrderController {
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var orderRepository: OrderRepository
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var inventoryClient: InventoryClient
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var circuitBreakerFactory: Resilience4JCircuitBreakerFactory
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var streamBridge: StreamBridge
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var traceableExecutorService: ExecutorService
    val log:org.slf4j.Logger=LoggerFactory.getLogger(OrderController::class.java)

    @PostMapping
    fun placeOrder(@RequestBody orderDto: OrderDto): String {
         log.info("Making Call to Inventory Service for SkuCode {}", lineItem.skuCode)
      
    }

}
```